# Use a variable to specifiy multiple columns in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a table with Column0,Column1, etc. I want create a result list for each row of data returned from the SQLalchemy execute statement.

```
    results = list(engine.execute('SELECT Data.Test_Results.*, Data.Files.* \
        FROM Data.Test_Results, Data.Files \
        WHERE Data.Files.Lot_Number like  \'900%\' '))
    
    for row in results:
                row_result.append(float(row.Col0))
                row_result.append(float(row.Col1))
                row_result.append(float(row.Col2))
```

I have 20 columns of data Col0 .. Col19. Can I use a variable to specify these columns instead of writing 20 lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a call to `fetchall()`:

```py
sql = """
SELECT Data.Test_Results.*
     , Data.Files.*
FROM   Data.Test_Results
 CROSS
  JOIN Data.Files
WHERE  Data.Files.Lot_Number LIKE '900%'
"""

results = engine.execute(sql).fetchall()
```

P.S. Don't use `SELECT *` in your SQL, list out the columns!

P.P.S. don't use `,` in your joins - specify the type (in this case as you have no join criteria what you've got is a `CROSS JOIN`).

Comment: Regarding the SELECT * : So, I can't get away from typing all 20 column names?

Comment: You should type out all the columns you need.